# how to write list of lists in python for large lists?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to write a list of lists into a file.
The list of lists looks like:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I wrote

```
with open("my_file.txt", 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join('{} {} {}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2]) for x in a if x is not None))
```

However, my list a now has lists inside it containing 19 values, a lot!
It looks like:

```
a = [[1,2,3,...,20], [21, 22, ..., 39], ...]
```

I do not want to write 16 more {} symbols and to modify the format command in there by adding another 16 x[i] where i = 3, 18.
Is there a smart way to do this?

In addition, is there an efficient way to do this? My list `a` will contain 10,000 lists of 19 values each.

Generally, are there any simple tricks to improve efficiency of writing such results into a file?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using another loop for the inner lists?

Comment: If plaintext format is a must, I would consider using e.g. [numpy.tofile()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html). No reason to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @kazemakase, ok, this is nice. I will try it now and I write here if I don't manage to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) work for you? `json.dump()` will create a nice file, and you can tweak the formatting as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the list and write each element of the sublist using `print()` with the `*` unpacking operator:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for sublist in a:
        if sublist is not None:    # filter out None items
            print(*sublist, file=fp)
```

The contents of `my_file.txt`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This will not print any `None` items to the file. If you actually intended to remove empty lists then you could just write:

```
if sublist:
    print(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to just serialize it to JSON:

```
import json
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
with open("my_file.txt", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(a, fp)
```

You can load it back like this:

```
import json
with open("my_file.txt") as fp:
    a = json.load(fp)
    print(a)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use JSON, you can convert your list to strings and then use join as you did previously:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = str(item)
with open("my_file.txt", 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join(a))
```

This is not as clean as JSON, but it does the job.

Comment: It is easier than using print, because when you load the data back from the file, you won't have to iterate over the lines and split them by a space to recreate the list. It is also safer than pickle when dealing with untrusted data. Read the warning in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html
It is also a universal data format, while pickle is Python-specific.

Answer (score 1):

> is there an efficient way to do this?

I would use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy.

```
import pickle

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
with open('my_list.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
with open('my_list.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    a_from_file = pickle.load(f)
    print(a_from_file)
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: @velenos14 this is the most efficient way to go.

Comment: Is there a simple way I can write to the file on separate rows? Say I have 3 sublists, how to get 3 rows each containing 1 sublist? Or it doesn't work this way I imagine?

Comment: The pickle format is binary and is not "human eye friendly". why do you care about rows, etc? Is there any human being that will have to read this file?

Comment: Totally understand. I wanted to read it to see if I haven't made any mistakes, i.e. the file is created as I would expect it to be. But I shall be able to do that by simply reading it back --> if the output of print() after loading the file is bad, then the file is not to be used as I expect.